# GetPixel always return 0 on png image

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, c#-4.0, bitmap

When i read image with `GetPixel()` color value is always black. My image is a png image.

I tried convert the image to bitmap before, but don't had success.

I believe which the problem isn't my code, because whether I open png image in Paint and only save it. The code read image correctly.

I load image like bellow

```
myImage = new Bitmap(fileName);
```

I need read image here

```
private void LoadImageMap(Bitmap value){
        for (int col = 0; col < value.Width; col++)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < value.Height; row++)
            {
                var color = value.GetPixel(col, row);
```

var color is black, always.

[Sample of the image...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t066u.png)

Comment: What the heck is `Image`? Why are you passing a `Bitmap` into your method and then totally ignoring it? Post your actual code. You've got 3 different images going around: `myImage`, `value`, and `Image`, and it's completely unclear what you're doing with them.

Comment: sorry `Image` is `value` parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PNG image there is transparency and when pixel is full transparency `GetPixel()` result with zero value to RGB colors.

Then my code needed of the one `if` to validate this case.

the solution was like bellow:

```
var color = value.GetPixel(x, y);

if(color.A.Equals(0))
{
    color = Color.White;
}
```

PNG use ARGB colors where A represent the alpha channel and whether alpha is zero this pixel has full transparence.

Comment: Technically pixels can perfectly have a colour set but still have their Alpha set to 0, mind you. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Ipu.png

Comment: No, this is exactly the problem in your image. The entire image _is_ black, but the pixels around the numbers have their alpha set to 0. But _their colour value is still black_. If you open the image in Gimp and split off the alpha as layer mask you can see the image pixels are all 100% black.

Answer (score 0):

Since you passed in the bitmap to your code, you need to actually use that variable when calling `GetPixel`.  Also, `ref` keyword is not needed in this case.

```
private void LoadImageMap(Bitmap value)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < value.Width; col++)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < value.Height; row++)
        {
            var color = value.GetPixel(col, row);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How I told I believe which code is correct and the problem is with png image format because whether I save this png in Windows Paint the code will read image.

Comment: Also I tried convert png image to bmp image with code bellow:

`using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        repainted.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
        var newImage = new Bitmap(stream, true);
        return newImage;
    }`

Comment: If your code works after you open and save your .png in Paint, then there must be a problem with the original .png file.  Where does it come from?

Comment: lol
my png source isn't in my eco system. I get the png from a web site. The png is a captcha image.